# Unable to change the primary language on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When creating my application I accidentally selected Spanish as the primary language. Now, in the App Information on iTunes connect when I try to change the primary language to "English" I get the following:

[image]

I have already added all the screenshots. I don't understand why it is not letting me change the primary language to English.

Comment: Can you check by deleting the provided screens and put them back again to check. I am not sure but it may work out. Let us know the rsult by this way.

Comment: Just did that same issue! I added screenshots for English US and it still complains!

Comment: I am facing the same issue currently. How did you fix it?

Answer (score -1):

As per Apple Guidelines:

**How can I change my app's default language?**
To change the default language of your app, select any previously added language from the Primary Language dropdown menu in the App Information section under App Store. To add a new language, a new binary must be submitted and reviewed.

If you localize your app, customers need to have the localized language set in their OS. If the app does not include any localization for the set OS language, the app reverts to your designated default language.

Offering your app in more than just the default language can help you reach additional customers and increase the number of app downloads.

**How can I edit localization information for a language that I have already added to my app?**
To edit a localization for shared metadata, select the language from the language menu in the App Information section under App Store. To edit localization information for platform specific metadata, you will need to select the language menu on the platform version page.

Saved changes will be visible on the App Store territory within 24 hours. You will not be able to edit locked information for a localization unless your app is in an editable state. For more information about editing localization information, review the **iTunes Connect Developer Guide**.

Comment: I am not able to change primary language of the app in new version. Primary Language Option under App Information on iTunes is not actionable there. Can anyone have any idea?

Comment: @Tejinder were you able to solve it? I am having the same issue